# undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromStringAndSize with tensorflow on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, tensorflow

trying to install tensorflow on heroku, in the end [it fails](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24) with:

```
pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromStringAndSize
```

requirements.txt:

```
numpy
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

install:

```
git push heroku master

Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 327 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote:        Collecting numpy (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading numpy-1.10.1.tar.gz (4.0MB)
remote:        Collecting tensorflow==0.5.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (10.9MB)
remote:        Installing collected packages: numpy, tensorflow
remote:          Running setup.py install for numpy
remote:        Successfully installed numpy-1.10.1 tensorflow-0.5.0
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 54.8MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v7
remote:        https://jalapenocandy.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To git@heroku.com:jalapenocandy.git
   9a2cc96..231788d  master -> master
```

looks good ! unfortunately, when i try:

```
heroku run bash

$python
python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 27 2015, 20:38:41)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py",
 line 4, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init
__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.client_lib import *
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client
/client_lib.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.session import InteractiveSession
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client
/session.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as tf_session
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap
_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap
_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_
pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromStringAndSize
```

anything i can do about it ?

Comment: solved with tensorflow-0.6.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is caused by your Python binary having an incompatible Unicode definition (UCS2) from the one assumed by the TensorFlow binary (UCS4).

At present, the best solution is to build TensorFlow [from source](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.html#source). The latest version does not use Unicode strings in the native extension, so this problem should not arise. When updated binaries are available, they will include this fix.

If you can't build from source on the target machine (for example when using Heroku), one option is to [build your own PIP package](http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.html#create-pip) on a different machine (with the same architecture), and add that to your `requirements.txt` instead.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, unfortunately i won't be able to build from src on that box (i'm not root, no apt-get, etc.). any eta for updated binaries ?

Comment: I added a suggestion: you can build your own PIP package on another box, and add that to your `requirements.txt`. We're currently compiling the patches that will go into the next release, so it should be ready soon, but I don't have an ETA.

Comment: @mrry, did this ever get patched? Having this same issue with 0.11.0 on Heroku

Comment: Ian: it's most likely that it was patched and then regressed again :(. The most reliable solution is probably to rebuild from source on your target platform, so that the appropriate definition is used.